# handling columns with whitespaces

Tags: bash, awk, columns

A hashing command gives the hash and the path separated by a whitespace:

```
k3j48fajsdjf4w8fj path to file/file 1.txt
```

I want to create a table where one column is the hash and the other column is the path to the file. That is,

```
k3j48fajsdjf4w8fj                path to file/file 1.txt
```

Some paths or filenames may have whitespaces on them. I have tried with awk and column, but I do not know how to tell them not to split paths or filenames with whitespaces. I am thinking in a way to tell them (or other tool that is capable of it) to split only by the first whitespace or by a fixed number of characters, as the first column should be a hash, but I am unable to find the way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like all you need is whichever of these you prefer:

```
sed 's/ /whatever/' file
awk '{sub(/ /,"whatever")}1' file
```

Change `whatever` to whatever string you want to replace that first blank char.